# Using convolution in computing distance numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have the following document that implies computing distance faster using fourier transform. I have implemented it using `numpy` however I fail to get the distance.

[image]

Here is my implementation:

```
if len(T)==len(Q) : # if both T and Q have the same number if numbers
  from scipy import signal 
  T_norm = np.mean(np.array(T)) # get the mean of T 
  sigma_t = 0 # set sigma of T intaially equal to zero
  for t in T : # for every number in T 
    sigma_part = pow(t-T_norm , 2) # get (t-T)^2
    sigma_t = sigma_t+sigma_part # add the previous sigma_t + sigma_part from the previous line
  sigma_t = sqrt(sigma_t) # get the sigma by square rooting its previous value 
  norm_Q = np.linalg.norm(np.array(Q)) # get norm of Q using numpy 
  norm_Q = np.array(Q)/norm_Q # get normalized Q by dividing by original Q / norm
  Q_dashed = np.flipud(np.array(norm_Q)) # reverse norm_Q
  F_T  = np.fft.fft(np.array(T)) # Do a Fourier transform on T
  F_Q = np.fft.fft(Q_dashed) # Do a Fourier transform on Q_Dashed
  F_T_Q = signal.convolve(F_T ,F_Q) # Do convolution for F(T) and F(Q)
  P = np.fft.ifft(F_T_Q)
  print(P)
  m = len(T) # m = number of numbers in T 
  D = np.sqrt(2*(m-((P)/sigma_t)))
  return D
else : # if T and Q have different number of numbers 
  print("Q and T have different dimensions ") ## print/report error
```

Comment: a bit of context would be nice. ...data as well...

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but the idea of using a FT is to avoid doing a convolution since it's expensive in time. So you have to multiply F_T and F_Q instead of convolving them because conv in time domain is multi in frequency domain

Comment: @JimmyFraiture yepp, in 1D computational effort of direct convolution is of order n^2 while FFT is n log n. So for large n it is worth doing FFT -> multiply -> IFFT as e.g. in numerical micromagnetism (2D). If it is 1D and say n < 100, it is probably not worth the trouble, though....as FFT implementation can be source of many mistakes.

Comment: Yes I know but what I'm saying is that in here in his code he do a convolution in the frequency domain. But he have to do a multiplication not a convolution. If he want to work with convolution he should do it directly in time domain. This is the mistake for me